# Can't get images to load with relative path

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

So I am remaking a site for my company moving from our wordpress site that has been failing. I am running into issue of using any image with a relative path. I can use the absolute path to the image on the wordpress site but that's not going to last so I need to be able to use relative. I am using asp.net to create the site.

My file path is like this:

```
Root
|-Images
|---Image in question
|-Views
|---Home
|------Index.cshtml (This is where I want the image showing up)
```

In my Index file I am trying to use an image as a background so I have the following:

```
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url("/../Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg");
        }
    </style>
```

So far I've tried:

```
/Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg
../Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg
../../Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg
/../../Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg
/../../../Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg
<Application>/Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg
```

I know I'm going a little too far with the "../" but I've been just trying different things to try and get this working. When using an absolute path for the background it works fine with no error.

Is there some special way I need to do this in asp.net that it just doesn't like these relative paths?

**Update**
[screenshot of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwPHM.png)

Issue turned out that I needed to have my images folder in the wwwroot folder. Thank you @thanzeel

Comment: home is under views which is under root. image is under root. From index in Home ../../Images/xxxx.jpg should work if you really have this structure

Comment: Yea that's what I originally thought but it's not working :/
Just set it to this: background-image: url("../../Images/Church-Main-Homepage-Image-3.jpg"); and it's still blank background

Comment: could you make a screenshot of file manager where we can see folders, with the right folder opened?

Comment: have you added the `app.UseStaticFiles();` to the middleware so your asp core apps can serve u static files?

Comment: Yes, app.UseStaticFiles(); is in my program.cs file

Comment: and are you images in the `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: They weren't. I just moved them there and now it's working. Thank you so much. Didn't realize they needed to be under the wwwroot folder

Comment: Does your server serve the entire "Chruchbudget" folder ?